# Error during execution: docker-compose run --rm api python3 manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django, docker, saleor

I am trying to install saleor on Linux Mint according to the instructions
https://docs.saleor.io/docs/3.0/developer/installation

When executing the command

```
docker-compose run --rm api python3 manage.py migrate
```

I get an error. This is the stack trace. How do I resolve this issue?

```
$docker-compose run --rm api python3 manage.py migrate
Starting saleor-platform_db_1 ... 
Starting saleor-platform_jaeger_1 ... done
Starting saleor-platform_redis_1  ... done

ERROR: for saleor-platform_db_1  a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

ERROR: for db  a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.22/containers/c015b9d2a6e0ba06c8cc393147db2a4eb1a0fc72d1ae2805e177b409bb8212db/start

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 625, in start_container
    container.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/container.py", line 241, in start
    return self.client.start(self.id, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 1095, in start
    self._raise_for_status(res)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint saleor-platform_db_1 (1b57cb27e18e4e18fad1fde3f6bebb573260974514be140c7e4e0d74d663b7b0): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use'")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.25.0', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
    command()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 128, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 896, in run
    run_one_off_container(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1343, in run_one_off_container
    project.up(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 565, in up
    results, errors = parallel.parallel_execute(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 112, in parallel_execute
    raise error_to_reraise
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 210, in producer
    result = func(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 548, in do
    return service.execute_convergence_plan(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 567, in execute_convergence_plan
    return self._execute_convergence_start(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 506, in _execute_convergence_start
    _, errors = parallel_execute(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 112, in parallel_execute
    raise error_to_reraise
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 210, in producer
    result = func(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 508, in <lambda>
    lambda c: self.start_container_if_stopped(c, attach_logs=not detached, quiet=True),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 620, in start_container_if_stopped
    return self.start_container(container)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 627, in start_container
    if "driver failed programming external connectivity" in ex.explanation:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 153, in apport_excepthook
    with os.fdopen(os.open(pr_filename,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/crash/_usr_bin_docker-compose.1000.crash'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.22/containers/c015b9d2a6e0ba06c8cc393147db2a4eb1a0fc72d1ae2805e177b409bb8212db/start

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 625, in start_container
    container.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/container.py", line 241, in start
    return self.client.start(self.id, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 1095, in start
    self._raise_for_status(res)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint saleor-platform_db_1 (1b57cb27e18e4e18fad1fde3f6bebb573260974514be140c7e4e0d74d663b7b0): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use'")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.25.0', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
    command()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 128, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 896, in run
    run_one_off_container(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1343, in run_one_off_container
    project.up(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 565, in up
    results, errors = parallel.parallel_execute(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 112, in parallel_execute
    raise error_to_reraise
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 210, in producer
    result = func(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 548, in do
    return service.execute_convergence_plan(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 567, in execute_convergence_plan
    return self._execute_convergence_start(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 506, in _execute_convergence_start
    _, errors = parallel_execute(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 112, in parallel_execute
    raise error_to_reraise
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 210, in producer
    result = func(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 508, in <lambda>
    lambda c: self.start_container_if_stopped(c, attach_logs=not detached, quiet=True),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 620, in start_container_if_stopped
    return self.start_container(container)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 627, in start_container
    if "driver failed programming external connectivity" in ex.explanation:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: The port for the database (5432) is already in use.

Comment: Thank you. 
To see who occupies the port:
sudo lsof -i :5432
It turned out that when deleting Postgresql, the services were still running:
:~$ systemctl | grep postgres

Comment: @KlausD. is there a reason for not giving your comment as an answer?  Just wondering if there is an advantage or disadvantage to a question not having an answer.  Also, dang that error message is kinda hidden away in all those stack traces, I've got a similar port in use problem.  +1

Comment: @EGHM Too simple, answered too often here, not a real programming issue.